# Add custom validation mechanism to abpBoilerplate dtos?

Tags: .net, dto, aspnetboilerplate

We create custom attribute "SpecificDateAttribute" for calss properties. How can We force all DTOs that have property with this attribute, validate  ICustomValidate method?

Comment: checkout following urls
https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Validating-Data-Transfer-Objects#DocCustomValidation

https://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2819

Comment: @AlperEbicoglu . Yes we can implement interface ICustomValidate , but should I implement it for each Dtos separately? Can I implement It once for all Dtos?

Comment: I miss why you need. Please, post some code

Comment: @GianpieroCaretti Please check my answer. thank you

Comment: @GianpieroCaretti can you check my answer please? Is it a right solution?

Answer (score 0):

I create base class for Dtos like this:

```
 public class AzmaBaseDto: ICustomValidate
{
    public virtual void AddAzmValidationErrors(CustomValidationContext context)
    {

    }

    public void AddValidationErrors(CustomValidationContext context)
    {
        var properties = this.GetType()
            .GetProperties();

        foreach (var a in properties.Where(p => p.IsDefined(typeof(ShamsiDateAttribute), false)))
        {
            #region
            var v = a.GetValue(this);
            if (v == null || DateTimeConvert.IsValidShamsiDate(v.ToString()) == false)
            {
                string _name = a.Name;
                if (a.IsDefined(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false))
                {
                    var ca = (DisplayAttribute)a.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (ca.Name.IsNullOrEmpty() == false)
                        _name = ca.Name;
                }
                context.Results.Add(new ValidationResult("Property value [" + _name + "] is not valid"));
            }
            #endregion
        }

                   AddAzmValidationErrors(context);
    }
}
```

and inherit Dtos form it. like this

```
  public class UpsertAccountingDocumentInput : AzmaBaseDto
{

    [ShamsiDate]
    public string Date { get; set; }



    public bool? SaveAsMemo { get; set; }



    public override void AddAzmValidationErrors(CustomValidationContext context)
    {
        if(SaveAsMemo==false && Date.IsNullOrEmpty()==false)
        {
            context.Results.Add(new ValidationResult("Put some error info"));
        }

        base.AddAzmValidationErrors(context);
    }
}
```

I think this can be one of the correct answers.

Comment: I think it works.
My doubt was about how you did your question: from you answer my understating now is you want to be sure all derived DTOs run your basic AddValidationErrors and them call your specific AddAzmValidationErrors. If so, it works